# SwiftUI Divider without affecting the size of its parent

Tags: macos, swiftui, layout

I have this SwiftUI sidebar view in a macOS app.

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Things")
            
            // This divider is causing the sidebar to stretch to
            // its maximum width. What I want is for it to be as wide
            // as the current size of the sidebar without affecting
            // it's size.
            Divider()

            Spacer()

            Button("New Thing") {
                print("New Thing")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Text("Content View")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HSplitView {
            SidebarView()
                .frame(minWidth: 200)
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 200)
        }.frame(width: 600, height: 400)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}
```

Without the divider:

[image: Without Divider]

With the divider:

[image: With Divider]

How can I add a divider that's only as wide as it needs to be to fill the sidebar, without affecting it's size?

Related, how can I left-align the content of the sidebar also without affecting its width?  I'm using `.alignment` on the `VStack` but if I try to make it expand to fill the view, it changes the video's size.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `NavigationSplitView` then it works out of the box:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        SidebarView()
    } detail: {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick with `HSplitView`, you could show the `Divider` as an overlay over the `VStack` of `SidebarView`.

- An overlay automatically adopts the same frame size as the view it is applied to. So the width of the overlay will be the ideal width of the `VStack`.
- To get the vertical spacing right, you could use a hidden version of some dummy text.
- You might also want to keep a hidden version of the divider in the main `VStack`, as a placeholder. If you apply `.fixedSize` to a `Divider` then it keeps its width to a minimum.

Like this:

```swift
struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Things")

            Divider().fixedSize().hidden()

            Spacer()

            Button("New Thing") {
                print("New Thing")
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                Text(".").hidden()
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: NavigationSplitView gives me a toolbar I didn't ask for.

Comment: @stevex Try `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .windowToolbar)`